# ¿ Por que al cerrar una ventana con una imagen de Matplotlib no finaliza la ejecucion del programa?

Tags: python, tkinter, matplotlib

Luego de cerrar la ventana que contiene la imagen no finaliza la ejecucion del programa sino que debo forzar a interrumpir la ejecucion.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

# Crear ventana de tkinter
ventana = tk.Tk()
ventana.geometry('400x400')

# Crear figura de Matplotlib
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 4, 2, 3, 5])

marco = tkinter.Frame(ventana)
marco.pack()
# Crear objeto FigureCanvasTkAgg
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=marco)
canvas.draw()

# Agregar objeto FigureCanvasTkAgg a la ventana de tkinter
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

# Ejecutar bucle principal de tkinter
ventana.mainloop()
```

Me indica que hay un error en el mainloop principal del programa.

```
C:\Users\afgb9\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe D:\Dropbox\AGPROGRAM\Python\prueba2.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Dropbox\AGPROGRAM\Python\prueba2.py", line 24, in <module>
    ventana.mainloop()
  File "C:\Users\afgb9\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1485, in mainloop
    self.tk.mainloop(n)
KeyboardInterrupt

Process finished with exit code -1073741510 (0xC000013A: interrupted by Ctrl+C)
```

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Me parace que lo que hace falta es indicar que se cierre la ventana de la figura

`plt.close('all')`

Guia de referencia:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.close.html